# Sending pdf file from server to client

Tags: java, angular

I want to send pdf file from server and display it in client side. I'm using server side technology as java and client side as angular 6. Please suggest me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try converting it to Base64 and get the string using an API can displaying in the client side?

Answer (score 2):

Using  **arraybuffer**

**service call:**

In File Service:

```
getFileFromServer(url){
   return this.httpService.getUploadedFile(url);
}
```

In HTTP service:

```
getUploadedFile(url:string){
        //just for authentication and file access.
        let headers = new HttpHeaders().append("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
        return this.httpClient.get(url, {responseType: 'arraybuffer',headers:headers});
    }
```

**in component:**

Using **Blob**

Blob reference -----> [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob)

> Here this.type = 'application/pdf'

For Example User Clicks on View Button:

than  `(click)="getPdfFile()"` will fire.

It will call service method to get response as `arraybuffer`

```
getPdfFile() {
  this.fileService.getFileFromServer(url).subscribe(responseData => {

                    //catch response as array buffer
                    this.showPdfFile(responseData, this.type);

                }, error => {

             //catch error if any
             console.log(error);
        });
    }

showPdfFile(data: any, type: string) {
            var blob = new Blob([data], { type: type });
            var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

            // it will open url to new tab.
            window.open(url);
        }
```

Comment: Please can you explain it details?

Comment: Yes you can get data from server in the form of array buffer. subscribe that data .    than use blob to display data (pdf or image or any browser supported type).

Comment: do you want some more details??

Comment: Yes sir i want more details. I'm trying what you have suggested before.

Comment: OK let me put more content.

Comment: still any problem than ping me back.

Comment: I'm getting Failed to load PDF document.

Comment: Are you getting response from server??

Comment: Put type = 'application/pdf'

Comment: Yes i'm getting response and excecting this code   const blob = new Blob([data.pdf], { type: 'application/pdf' });

      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        window.open(url);

Comment: Don't put data.pdf direct it should be arraybuffer.

Comment: Path pdfPath = Paths.get("D:\\invoice.pdf");
    
    byte[] pdf = Files.readAllBytes(pdfPath);
    
    Buffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(pdf);
    
    
    sr.setPdf(buf); this is my server code

Comment: Right. But add array buffer in request. Check my code in answer.

Comment: getUploadedFile(url:string){
        //just for authentication and file access.
        let headers = new HttpHeaders().append("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
        return this.httpClient.get(url, {responseType: 'arraybuffer',headers:headers});
    } Like this.